# How can I get status(Sent, Pending, Error) of sendmail using gmail google client API?

Tags: php, sendmail

```
$strRawMessage = "From: aa@gmail.com \r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "To: reciever@gmail.com\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($EMAILSUBJECT) . "?=\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "$EMAILBODY\r\n";
$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($mime);
$mailOutPut = $service->users_messages->send('aa@gmail.com', $msg);
```

Here, aa@gmail.com is Invalid email address.
So how can I get status for mail send.
As currently It gives me error => "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/Email/messages/send

Comment: Wrap `send` in a try/catch. If it fails, you have an exception that needs to be solved at a higher level. If it succeeds, you can inspect the object returned.

Comment: So you are using the Unix program `sendmail`?